# Unit Testing Inbound Mail Service on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-python27

I have a handler in my application for processing inbound emails. Is there some way to unit test that functionality? I don't see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is about testing handlers in general on GAE you can use the [WebTest](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) framework to accomplish this. If your question is about testing the Mail service specifically you can use the Mail service stub provided by [TestBed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting).

Comment: To my knowledge, that is only for testing outbound mail, not inbound.